# How to get file from SFTP server

Tags: php

I've been working at this for the last 2 days to no avail. I've also searched on StackOverflow for a solution but I couldn't find one that works for me.

I'm trying to pull a .csv file from a SFTP server. I found out you cannot do this with a default installation of PHP. I found 2 solutions.

1) Enable the ssh2_sftp extension in my PHP. I couldn't get this to work. I downloaded the required files, put them in my php/ext folder as directed, and modified the line in php.ini as required. Wouldn't work.

2) Use phpseclib. Couldn't get this to work as you need to use composer with it and composer wont load my php.ini because I have curl enabled?

Are there any other solutions for logging into a sftp server?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you have `root` access on the machine you're working with, why not use `scp`?  It's a native php function so long as you have `shell_exec` enabled, and the user `www-data` (or whatever you call your `httpd` user) has `shell` access.

```
<?php
    $connection = ssh2_connect('your_remote_server', 22); //remote connection
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password'); //authentication
    ssh2_scp_recv($connection, '/remoteServer/whatever/yourFile.csv', '/localServer/yourNewFilename.csv'); //remote file -> local file
?>
```

**NOTE**
I have used this, but I also store the "username" and "password" in a `MySQL` database using `bcrypt` with a minimum cost of 12.  More about that [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Comment: That uses the ssh2_sftp extension I mentioned in my original post. I couldnt seem to get it working.

Comment: Maybe I'm not installing right? The people who come out with these things don't really document them well or provide clear instructions.

Comment: Are you on a Debian distro?  Have you tried simply `sudo apt-get install libssh2-1 php-ssh2 -y` and then `sudo service apache2 restart`?

Comment: I'm currently using on my desktop which is using XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: In that case it's a little less straight forward ..  You have to make sure that you install `ssh2` for the version of `PHP` you have, AND you have to be sure that your'e installing for the correct OS (64 bit vs 32).  Furthermore, I think (don't quote me) that, `ssh2` for Windows only goes to `PHP 5.5`.